# Workaround to simplify the syntax when calling function classes with generic arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I am aware that typescript doesn't allow a static member of a class to access a generic passed to the class like this

```js
abstract class Base<T> {
    static genericMethod(props: [K in keyof T]?: T[K]): [K in keyof T]?: T[K] { // <-- Static members cannot reference class type parameters.
        return props
    }
}
```

I need this because a second class, let's say named `Child` extends class `Base` and inherits its methods with itself passed as a generic

```js
class Child extends Base<Child> {
    a?: string
    b?: number
    c?: number
}
```

In such a way that I am able to call the inherited methods with the right generic type

```js
Child.genericMethod({ a: 3 }) // <-- I want this to be an error, because type of "a" is "string"
```

#### What I have tried

I have tried to wrap `Base` into a function, so that its static members can accept the function's generic

```js
function Base<T>() {
    return class {
        static genericMethod(props: { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] }): { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] } {
            return props
        }
    }
}

class Child extends Base<Child>() {
    a?: string
    b?: number
    c?: number
} 

Child.genericMethod({ a: 0 }) // Ok. Error as needed. "a" is not of type "number"
```

Now it works as i intended, but the syntax got a little ugly.

#### Context

This static method gets added to the `Child` class, which is defined by the user, via a decorator.

```
function classDecorator<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(constructor: T) {
    return class extends constructor {
        static genericMethod(props: any) {
            return props // <-- this is an example implementation!
        }
    }
}

// User defined Class 
@classDecorator
class Child {
    a?: string
    b?: number
    c?: number
}

Child.genericMethod() // <-- Error. genericMethod doesn't exist!
```

Doing this way, Typescript has no idea that `Child.genericMethod()` exists because decorators only exist at runtime (I *hope* this will change in the future). To make the compiler aware about the presence of `genericMethod` I create a phantom class which the user defined `Child` class will extend, inheriting its methods.

```js
abstract class Base {
    static genericMethod(props: any): any { //<-- I need to use 'T' here but I can't!
        return undefined
    }
}

@classDecorator
class Child extends Base {
    a?: string
    b?: number
    c?: number
}

Child.genericMethod() // <-- OK. Now the compiler knows that generichMethod is present.
```

I need to pass the type of `Child` to `Base`, because `genericMethod` needs it to check for the correct args and return value types.
Which brings us once more to the beginning.

#### Problem

This is an external API and it doesn't look simple to my eyes. Having some user doing `class A extends B<A>()` looks a bit dirty. I think that having to repeat `A extends B<A>` isn't the best plus someone using it might forget to call `B<A>()`. I'd like the user to simply do `class A extends B` which is much easier to remember and read.

#### Question

Is there some other way around this that I didn't think about? Is there some way to make `Base` infer the class it is being extended by and use that as its generic?
[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAUEMGdoSwHYHNRIKYLQJzgY1AC4D2o0BkBeoAtmgQBZEAm0oAUGwGYCuCulRBKABCMNAB4AKgD4AFAEpQAbzag1oLHW5YhuADYxWK9SdLlK+AA6RNCAgFk6jJrMtYil6AC5loANoA0qCIoADWaACeRJygkgC6APw+koFxoAC+8j5K-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-OJSnbi2zLgSQkEkWcsHwVQe7YFQSkJBwAqgPxgnosMUrYn0tFCMsYAxqAADqu7qTgwzREB-aKMWYVWQefoAeOK4src2Y9Me0VUCyETUJOyltOSPiUhKeoWsa2BmsVVqdCsACq8DUnRNhobQrKIGQaCQCFMQmRKSqoBg1n4EwcDlgQ2oUSst73sMQ60QitCoW+OyicMnyrlqTEbgwYVLaAoXwt1x5IfsSqoehdjaQ+kC4K+lgfPG-LNg0CF4rFgFCqwrHZrm8CXhRPB8EcTF+Zu76oVIcgNckSxtDUdT8gYqLGDSZDqlYNgYY4DCug0njZLknJhJEoXFMkZSZLjgT4wUROJCTARpOkFS0iYMM6I+jRtCYrScx09nw6wLGsScTknBxmLSlMuJoEDDAg0gsgCwJQuC9gHFLNxPm8dcCtscLKsudcxG7NytivsMg3DZWk6cubaAVoqISHKwRCMkIIpiJibiXPAggUWSFIEFSSBFT4holaaJjmiHlqlekQA) with some (not working) ideas.

Comment: Is this just a typo?  You have `class Child extends Base<Child> {}` but `Base` is a class factory function you need to *call*, like `class Child extends Base<Child>() {}`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/m0AyPW).  Does that not work how you want?  I'm trying to figure out if this question is actually in need of an answer, or just caused by forgetting to call the class factory function.  What should we do here?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to call `Base`. That is my bad. It'd be clean if passing the generic and the call into the `extends` statement could be avoided, but I don't think there is any other way.

Comment: I am going to edit the question. Now that the typo is fixed, I'd like a cleaner solution. This is an external API and I'd want it to be as simple as possible. I want to know if there is another way to do it, without the need to pass the generic of the same class being created and call the class being extended.

Comment: So I think I'm not understanding the purpose of the generic type parameter `T`; it looks like maybe you mean for it to be instance type of the current class (which is why you are writing `class Foo extends Base<Foo>`.  If so I can eliminate the type parameter and get what I think is the desired behavior as shown in [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NVkZlm).  If that meets your needs I can write up an answer; if not, please tell me what I'm missing.

Comment: Yes, this is just what I was looking for. Thank you. Please provide an answer explaining how you achieved it.

Comment: Is it possible to make this approach work on instance method too?

Comment: ?? That looks like a separate/followup question and probably belongs in its own post. Possibly you can just use the `this` type directly in your instance methods, but without a [mre] I can't be sure.  And probably not here in the comments of an existing question.

Comment: using `this` directly worked. I want to give you my thanks once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually you'd like to use the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) to refer to the "current" class, but there is currently no direct support for `this` types in static methods in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) for the relevant feature request.

Luckily there are workarounds mentioned in that GitHub issue as well, such as one [in this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863#issuecomment-242782664) suggesting making the static method [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and give it a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters).  For your example, that looks like:

```
abstract class Base {
    static parentMethod<T extends Base>(
        this: new (...args: any) => T,
        props: { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] }
    ) {
        return props
    }
}
```

The idea is that when someone calls `Something.parentMethod()`, the compiler will see that `Something` is of the `this` type, and so it will try to infer `T` such that `Something` is of type `new (...args: any) => T`.  In other words, it will infer `T` to be the instance type of the `Something` class.  And now you can use `T` in the `props` parameter as desired.

Let's test it out:

```
class Child extends Base {
    a?: string
    b?: number
    c?: number
}

Child.parentMethod({ a: "", b: 2 }); // okay
Child.parentMethod({ a: 3 }); // error
// ----------------> ~
// number is not assignable to string
```

Looks good.  When you call `Child.parentMethod()`, the compiler infers that `T` is `Child`, and thus the call looks like `Base.parentMethod<Child>()`, and the `props` argument is of type `Partial<Child>`.  So `{a: "", b: 2}` is accepted, but `{a: 3}` is an error because the `a` property is not a `string`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgg3gFAIkKTAQCWsCADsFDgHYQCyOEAFgPYAmAPABUEOAB4RmvDNjA4AfAApipFV0pgAXAiY4A7ggUA6YwwDmmhMCYBPAJQIAvHISCANMpUlaUbrQv4EAG0AaQRKJgQAaxxrbgAzFwBdAH4tQRDEhABfDwR7Ik9SRggAVygI718wXJycwhQ0DABhTkpkXhFxSWlcAlzgVLJocNNckEGmEoBbEBwoXNgJ6dn5upa23kN6RhZ2Lj4FAOAtACIT1wQQLQAmbNsAbgQAeieEbkjga0J19q2GZjYHB4vEOli0AGY7o8XiIoD55jCALTIlGotGI5wAP0IMMmMzmYQwTG4iEalFMTFAyDwEG4QygIyAA)

Answer (score 1):

What about instead of a static method use a generic function like this:

```js
function genericMethod<T>(props: { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] }): { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] } {
  return props
}

genericMethod<Child>({ a: 0 })
```

Comment: In this library, the static method is added to the class via a decorator. Typescript only needs to know about its presence while the implementation resides in the class decorator. I think I am going to add additional info about the use case