# How to restrict the allowed properties of a class in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, typescript-class

I need to restrict the properties names and the types a class can have. The only way I have found to do this is the following

```js
type ForbiddenKeys = "x"|"y"|"z"

type Allowed = string|number|boolean|Set<string|number>|Array<string|number>|null|undefined
type AllowedObject = { [s:string]: Allowed | AllowedObject } & { [F in ForbiddenKeys]?: never }

class A {
    [s:string]: Allowed | AllowedObject 
    private x?: never
    private y?: never
    private z?: never
    static scan(): string {
        return "DUMMY static method return value"
    }
    save(): void {
        // DUMMY empty method
    }
}
```

this class will be used as an abstract class to make the compiler aware of *hidden* methods and forbidden property names that extending classes will have. The extending classes, will in fact have a decorator applied to them where the real logic of the methods resided

```js
function addMethods<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(constructor: T) {
    return class extends constructor {
        static scan() {
            // Real logic goes here
            return "scan() static method got executed."
        }
        save() {
            console.log(`${JSON.stringify(this)} has been saved`)
            // REAL method logic goes here
        }
    }
}

@addMethods
class B extends A { // <-- Only properties definitions go here while methods are added by the decorator.
    x?: string // <-- Error as needed. We don't want "x" here
    a?: string
    b?: number
    c?: {
        d?: boolean
        //y?: string // <-- Error as needed. We don't want "y" here
    }
}
```

Follows an example usage

```js
const b = new B()
b.a = "A"
b.b = 0
b.save() // <-- return value: void. Compiler must be aware of this. Decorator logic gets executed.
const scan = B.scan() // <-- const scan: string. Compiler must be aware of this.
console.log(scan) // <-- Prints: "scan() static method got executed."
```

This works until I need to work with the property names of the child class. Even a simple type which iterates over the properties of B, will not behave as desired because `keyof T` includes `[s:string]`

```js
type Props<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]?: T[K]
}

const props: Props<B> = {
    a: "abcd",
    b: 0,
    anyProperty: "anything" // <-- No error. I need an error here.
}
```

The following type is a closer (simplified) example of what I do really need. It is a type which adds the forbidden properties to each key of the class and so does with its nested objects

```js
type AddProps<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends Allowed ? { 
        [F in ForbiddenKeys]?: T[K] 
    } : T[K] extends (AllowedObject|undefined) ? AddProps<T[K]> : never
}

function addProps<T>(propsToAdd: AddProps<T>) {
    return propsToAdd
}

addProps<B>({  // <-- We don't want errors here.
    a: { x: "some string" }, 
    b: { y: 0 },
    c: { 
        d: {
            z: true
        }
    }
})
```

This cannot be done, because `keyof T` includes `[s:string]` and not only the properties I declared in `class B`

### Question

Is there a way to achieve what I am after?
[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwEYEsAmaIDsDSEQDOUAvFAEQAeZAPmSDWQF5kBQLokUAggDY9wB3CGhJQCwBCiwBzalgCuAWyQQE1JHDg8IAQyzUAyhGAAecZJlylKhAD5qXBAh0gzEqbIXLV9+VkwAZlLC1DB+AMbAKHBY7ODQvPxCaADySABWEJGiAN5QANoEAFzmHgC6Rdx8gsJQ1FVJwmmZ2QC+UABkUHn5MFBSsIioGNh4hGUA-JVYEABuqlCtbAERUTFQOhgAssYAFnBoBCYAKlAQFMDYh91QMwJQABQAdC86CNLFG1gg+WUAlJUcu1WrYHuEYuZ5JFEJVjn9uiwoEioAhjPIEFgoOEeDoCERzpd-ERwVhIdCEAjkVSxMAdFFwmJwnoHvCcojqRyAPScqAAJV0PCg-GkKAZ0jgECIu1UEHZHKpqOA6MxZAITKwLJpdNFUEUewOUHFwDOFCy8kuaCerHlizl1IIOnmmrZNqpJIIWggT2FDwABgASHIAKQMKQAck9SjIUAEQA9gLsUAQ-u1drioCpsGJHcJfX87TbuXyAKJcAAyuv1ImFOvFkqg0tRBeRSypSyWLGxuKIXEpyMKJXcMgqDRqInqiTHzSyxrtYEkszp0AoU1uc1Uc4XS6gIFXM3mCE3KEXlygjD368PVPE2oZauZAJpFmkfY5iuV5AAIgBVLZbACaWr0pWCYGu+GJQIuPDyBA1otnaDpOo+sxwOgr7UkWP5-oBECKGAoAgfsaB2u2bAAAKbGgOygYcnY4niUAAEImoS1y9nkRYmAAtFxUApFgPAgFA85wJACBRPWgRSCgaykoacANjKUACIm2iEQcRBvNAlG1EgQkJtAmDgs4wCIE8dorpUUYvpxPFQMWTiIBsRAzMIwhPFAADqhkxAA5MaAh6MalBkIpTZUjoq7WXaSB7tYG5uquLrymgq4aJ6ejNki3K7lZQ42Ty3G8Q5CBOemrmYJaXk+Vg-nKUF5D0GFsptiwHbusaSCiHcTEsiwSBPDoohkFwrADV1pAAAz9ZGOaarZvHgZiUEwZUKHoB5ADCcB4Sg2gUoo8jiBm2mBaiUBwAEUAJkmHmflkiB0k5NZisY+KmuE5ruSQxC-X9xC2J2ELGvemKkIxkbqvNhV2R1jJ6Hlz5bTtYB7Qsh3HSoGxndAl3XYmBDme6nrenA0gPKD8ILVAAAKFjAJ8qpQ-CN7AXqNHyca5xmhaVo-f9AuC0LwsC4DcScHTolHMcti5Ha+QANb9JiCv4HjxyTLCitlG1bBwyJYCfJLhsmIxsukMlSI6JUZA6Eg4RoGQAA0MWVJNLsRd8xuqKANt6CAN0yKF1PefVWDGnoZyORSjZerrLBFqHFX40m13xNdClY2AcB4igSDaOLCQYMb0vm+hivK1AqsgOrmtQMc2ssVcPbVMkUATDcWUFH0AzwMg6CYLg+AEHXDcK2UUAkVAWvj03RKPJOyTTpE1B+FJMxoPCHdcMXpUm2PZSy9Ml7x0WAASgjKdAAh7YKR3QCNu9S6FHCyisWCRNEmKUSXJyggbBBjhwB3mgSoIDf4y1ZHaJawk96AOARgeOP84Gm1BHkKAIcap1UCuHKOpUEBShlOZCKgIoAUBth6PUT4PChVaE7SeVIkCkJAG7RYHtkThFIV3UB6EbSMEqBIGCXdWzwVaH8IAA)

Comment: Aside: the index signature `{[S: string]: ...}` is unconventionally named.  That `S` is a *dummy key name*, not a *type parameter*.  Key names are usually written like other identifiers, in lowerPascalCase, like `k` or `key`... so `{[k: string]: ...}` is preferred.

Comment: I am aware that `[S:string]` is just a dummy name and that it can be `[anything:string|number|symbol]`. I used an uppercase S just to better distinguish it from the K in some tests I've conducted privately. I'd be very grateful if I could get some advice on the matter of the question too :)

Comment: It's a dummy *key* name, and uppercase key names are not conventional.  I suggest you change it to `s` so as not to be a distraction.  I assure you I *am* looking at the question content, but it is distracting to deal with unconventional names while doing so.

Comment: A little more targeted aside: I don't understand why you are using `class`es and then not using them to construct instances.  Shouldn't you just be using `interface`s?  Writing `class Z {x?: string}` and then `const z: Z = {x: "abc"}` is weird, since someone might expect `z instanceof Z` to be `true` when it is in fact `false`.  In my suggested approach I'm going to abandon `class` entirely unless you have some motivated reason for using them instead of interfaces (and put example code that shows this)

Comment: So my approach here might be something like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAQQRm).  There's really no specific type that represents "forbid these keys recursively" and doesn't add a big `string` index signature everywhere to mess you up.  Instead, I'd write a generic constraint like `VerifyAllowed<T>` and then use generic helper functions to make sure nobody's passing in forbidden things.  Does that meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining it.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: The reason for using classes was partially explained in the question. Parent class 'A', is like a declaration of what properties (and methods) can be presento on child classes that extend it. This connects to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73419350/workaround-to-simplify-the-syntax-when-calling-function-classes-with-generic-arg) you answered. I need to use classes here, they *will* be constructed and have constructor and methods applied via decorators. The abstract class is needed to declare these hidden type rules.

Comment: Can you adapt my suggested approach to your code, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3XXjW)?  If so then maybe we can remove the `class` part from this question since it's not really motivated by the example code.  If you need `class` in this question then I suggest changing the example code to do a `new` somewhere.  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: I have updated the question and the playground link with more detailed info on usage. Please be aware that it has been simplified but now its much closer to what I have

Comment: I was hoping you'd make the code in this question simpler and not more complicated, but okay.  So [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXjjVm) shows how I'd approach this.  Does that address your question or not?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, I might run away screaming at this point.

Comment: Yes it does. I was hoping to not involve including `implements` in the user code (`class B extends A implements VerifyAllowed<B>`) but i guess that is not an option.

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that there is no specific object type in TypeScript which constrains value types without adding a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).  If I want to say that an object can only have, say, `boolean`-valued properties, then the only specific object type available to me is `type Boo = {[k: string]: boolean}`.  But `keyof Boo` will be `string`, which you don't want.

Since we can't really write `AllowedObject` as a specific object type, we can try writing it as a generic *constraint*.  That is, `VerifyAllowed<T>` checks a candidate type `T` for whether it is allowed or not.  If `T extends VerifyAllowed<T>`, then it is allowed, otherwise it is not.

Here's one possible implementation of that:

```
type VerifyAllowed<T> = T extends Allowed ? T :
    T extends object ? {
        [K in keyof T]: K extends ForbiddenKeys ? never : VerifyAllowed<T[K]>
    } : never
```

If `T` is `Allowed`, then `VerifyAllowed<T>` will resolve to just `T` (and thus `T extends VerifyAllowed<T>` will be true).  Otherwise, if `T` is an `object` type, we [map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) each property `T[K]` to `VerifyAllowed<T[K]>` unless the key `K` is one of the `ForbiddenKeys` in which case we map it to `never`.  So if none of the keys are forbidden, then `T extends VerifyAllowed<T>` succeeds if all the properties are allowable, and fails otherwise.  If even one key is forbidden, then that property is mapped to `never` and then `T extends VerifyAllowed<T>` will be false.  And finally, if `T` is neither `Allowed`, nor an `object`, then it's some primitive we don't want (like `symbol`) and so we just return `never` so that `T extends VerifyAllowed<T>` will be false.

---

Okay, so how can we use that?  One way if you're using `class` definitions is to put it in [an `implements` clause](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#implements-clauses) to catch any non-compliant `class`es right way.  This isn't necessary, but without it you'd only catch the error the first time you tried to pass a class instance into something.  Anyway, it looks like this:

```
class A implements VerifyAllowed<A> {
    static scan(): string {
        return "DUMMY static method return value"
    }
    save(): void {
    }
}    

@addMethods
class BadB extends A implements VerifyAllowed<BadB> {
    a?: string
    b?: number
    c?: { // error! // Types of property 'y' are incompatible
        d: boolean
        y: string
    }
}
```

Oops, we made a mistake and put `y` in there.  Let's remove that:

```
@addMethods
class B extends A implements VerifyAllowed<B> { // okay
    a?: string
    b?: number
    c?: {
        d: boolean
    }
}
```

---

Whether or not we use `implements VerifyAllowed<>` in our `class` declarations, we can still catch mistakes by making any function that accepts "allowed" things [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  For example:

```
function acceptOnlyAllowedThings<T>(t: VerifyAllowed<T>) {

}

const badB = new BadB();
const b = new B();

acceptOnlyAllowedThings(badB); // error! c.y is bad
acceptOnlyAllowedThings(b); // okay
```

---

Now that we have put the constraint in there we can define `Props<T>` as the same thing as [the `Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype), because there's no string index signature messing you up:

```
type Props<T> = Partial<T>; // <-- this is just Partial

const props: Props<B> = {
    a: "abcd",
    b: 0,
    anyProperty: "anything" // error!
}
```

---

And the same thing goes for `AddProps<T>`: you can recursively turn `T` into `AddProps<T>` without worrying about string index signatures:

```
type AddProps<T> = T extends VerifyAllowed<T> ? {
    [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends Allowed ? {
        [F in ForbiddenKeys]?: T[K]
    } : AddProps<T[K]>
} : never;

const test: AddProps<B> = {
    a: { x: "some string" },
    b: { y: 0 },
    c: {
        d: { z: true }
    }
}
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoLIFMoAs6oDOAPACqJYAeUWYRiA3omFgO4AUAdN8gE4DmhAFwowATwDaAXQCUIhgF9ECgHzsICQlF4hocXiNIzGAKETnEvHCF5IIAG2SFCFarXoawWnXt6mLAYhayLAQQRDIYOzGDGaB8QD0CYgASljI9oj2cPwwYfxwWC64WFZx8QFWUDZIAESEEVHGwaGIALY4+KiIBVCuWBAgNKicteWBCuMBhMgAbljR-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-U3TRJpmlhWHI6ITC+ThkBm2ooTGHavhmgAGbbrgBRZwVqBhamQWohAO2oABpai+R7TveT4fj+JDAU5ZavD6e8kFZMjrkaLbVi1LYcnYUHjBu0HFlvMJQK6VE+ioAYhkBUZEADMVEAABR0nrY1JvhYAyGNfWSxBiAAWiZxBnhcF5EGLEAtCpvSYAyAkJq08mRDJuBiRIRLWWvcxkBEe6vggVBXpEkRTpevjxHF3SiQVyIxGeO5OXBZnWYAdTJVhIj6SIKCtfREBKKxOCwjdkDqhqmpaoaONQTruvYKbuJkem5Id3hlIgTgxFrFxg5MD36sa5rWvPf2uruQgg9DhnUvS0UgyhdAdYpma8xok9BvTmNhww6tzIbJsW1IKQxNIBdqK7RB07r2XAgkclG57PtPQHRlCDbwwF2XRARGL1BS-nOlFywufZrHJbhZoLR55L8mEsp-v5aSygFbWDpAI8-hOQUTWAi+eREDcxBTuUe+LAgeRCqfwURG0WCmEvJAA)